# Configuring many-to-many relationship in EntityFramework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using ASP.NET MVC to create a sample web app, and I want to configure many-to-many relationship. I have products and transactions. I want to make each transaction include one or more products. I have a code first classes defined like following:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

}

public class Transaction
{
    public int TransactionID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

}
```

Then, I added some stuff to my `ApplicationDbContext`, and finally it looks like this:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    //protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    //{
    //    modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction>().HasMany(x => x.Products).WithMany();
    //}

    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
}
```

Afterwards, I enabled migrations, and added some test data that I want to be displayed in my database. The test data can be found below:

```
protected override void Seed(MyApp.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)
{
    var pr = new List<Product>();
    pr.Add(new Product { Name = "Book" });
    pr.Add(new Product { Name = "Table" });
    pr.Add(new Product { Name = "Chair" });

    pr.ForEach(i => context.Products.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Name, i));
    context.SaveChanges();

    context.Transactions.AddOrUpdate(
        t => t.Products,
        new Transaction { Products = new List<Product>(pr.Where(p => p.Name == "Book" || p.Name == "Table")) },
        new Transaction
        {
            Products = new List<Product>(pr.Where(p => p.Name == "Chair" || p.Name == "Book" || p.Name == "Table"))
        }
    );

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Then, I created a new migration, and updated the database. But, when I checked the tables, there was just `TransactionID` column in the table of transactions, and there wasn't the `Products` column holding the ids of the products. Instead there was a new column in the product table named `Transaction_TransactionID`, but it was holding id of the latest transaction which the product was member of. So, the relationship is not quite right.

As can be seen I also have a method commented out, where I wanted to manually specify the many-to-many relationship. But, when I uncomment it and try to update the database, I get a few errors, from which one of them is:

> IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined.
>   Define the key for this EntityType

Any idea to achieve what I want? At the later part of the project, I need to query for transactions, and find which products were involved in which transactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make a many to many relationship a third table will be created for it, which contains the primary keys of the two tables.

You should specify the many to many relation in the context class, as you did in the commented part. But, as the `ApplicationDbContext` inherits from `IdentityDbContext` class you should call `base.OnModelCreating` in order to apply model definitions of the `base.OnModelCreating` as well.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction>().HasMany(x => x.Products).WithMany();
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```